# Find View By Id throwing null error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have built a login in page, it working however now it is throwing a null when i call `FindViewByID`, I have set the content view and still the same.

CS Code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

   Button SignInButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.singin);
}
```

layout

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/singin"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/password"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:background="#307FC1"
  android:text="Login"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: share error logcat..

Comment: you have a typo in your code. It might be the cause `singin` should be probably `signin`

Comment: Your code looks good. Just make sure that the `Button` with id: "singin" is found inside `Main.axml` and not in any other file.

Comment: First, the code you provided works well. Second, please check `singin` in your `Resource.Designer.cs` file. if it doesn't exits in the file, please clean and rebuild your project. Third, make sure the id `singin` only exits your `Main` layout.

Answer (score -2):

change this line

```
Button SignInButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.singin);
```

to

```
Button SignInButton = (Button) FindViewById(Resource.Id.singin);
```

Comment: @GurpreetBhopal Make sure, `android:id="@+id/singin"` within `Main` layout

Answer (score -2):

I don't see errors, expect the wrong uppercase (made by ND1010_'s answer too) in the find view by id call...I don't know if that could be the error, but I guess you can give it a try

Change `Button SignInButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.singin)`

To `Button SignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singin)`